# Custom component FormControl pass value to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom form control component implementing controlValueAccessor and working fine when used directly in a formGroup.

But now I'm trying to use my custom form control component in a "wrapper" component and using this wrapper component instead in my form.

I'm really struggling to do so, do I need to implement again a controlValueAccessor on my wrapper component ?
I just want my wrapper component to pass the value to the form.

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kllvf

Comment: Hi I guess you were working with the Udemy course by Neil Cummings, right?

Comment: No just a personal project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing `controlValueAccessor` would be an option. Passing FormControl as an input an alternative: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kllvf-lw1pwn?file=src/app/profile-editor/profile-editor.component.html